# javascript input from keyboard without "prompt()"method popup (like pascal readln or gwbasic input or c++ scanf/gets/cin ...)

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard

```
Hi, can javascript implement a function to read input from keyboard, 
like pascal readln, gwbasic input, C scanf/gets, C++ cin?

Just to complete what follows:

    < head>
    <script>function input(){
    /* ?????????????? */
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    alert("Enter something");
    a=input();
    alert("You entered: "+a);
    </script>

I am an absolute beginner and I just tried to copy and paste some code from some books, unsuccesfully.

Tnx!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by calling a function once the keypress event is sent from the browser:

```
window.onkeypress = function(key) {
    alert(key.charCode);
};
```

Will return the charCodes that can be translated with this list: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.

This [library](https://github.com/ChazzleDazzle/GetCharCode) might help you with the translation. It would then look like:

```
window.onkeypress = function(key) {
    alert(GetChar(key.charCode));
};
```

Edit: Ok, you want to output the sequence when 'Enter' is pressed. To achieve that, you can use an array to store the pressed keys:

```
var chars = [];
window.onkeypress = function(key) {
    var keyName = GetChar(key.charCode);
    if (keyName !== 'enter') {
        // store the current keyName
        chars.push(keyName);
    } else {
        // output the pressed chars as string
        alert(chars.join(''));
        // clear chars array
        chars = [];
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, I can't figure how to read the entire sequence of keys when RETURN is hit . 
 In my purposes,  input() should read the sequence of keys  and a=input()    should load the entire sequence (till return is hit) into a.

Comment: @GiuseppinaRossi: I updated the above thread with an example.